# Ensuring Hyperlinks are working on a website

Tags: testing, web

Is there any way to use vanilla javascript to test test all the hyperlinks on a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xenu's Link Sleuth is a tool that you can use to check for all the links on the site .

It verifies normal links, images, frames, plug-ins, style sheets, scripts, etc. It displays a report of all the links along with its status .
You just have to add the url of the site and then it does its work .

Hope it helps you .